# Android Bluetooth Low Energie Service

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Having a strange issue besides the app and BLE Device
Im using BroadcastReceiver to receive the connection and data from the BLE device and have a service for the Call to the BLE Device

Is it a good idea to have a Service on each activity that uses the BluetoothLeService (Service) since my app randomly crashses when switching activities. its there for writing characteristics and descriptors.

I need my BluetoothLeService  on more than one Activity and im binding it on each activity is this bad practice? if so please does someone can point me to the right direction since im new to Android development.

Answer (score 2):

We are using the BLE Service as singleton. So we have only one instance. We are using it this way in several Apps and had not problems so far. We developed a cross platform implementation based on Monkey robotics. "Unfortunately", you have to use MvvMCross. We are currently working on a version that can be used without. So if you have problems, you could compare our Implementation with yours: https://github.com/xabre/MvvmCross-BluetoothLE